# Can Page_Load() Be Async

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms

Can a `Page_Load()` method be `async`?  I ask as if I have declared as such

```
protected void Page_Load()
```

Everything loads as it should.  If I have it declared as such

```
protected async void Page_Load()
```

the `Page_Load()` breakpoint is not hit, nor does the `catch()` block get hit.

Now I am trying to set my `Page_Load()` method as `async` in order to have 3 different stored procedures execute to completion before the page is fully rendered.  If I do not have my `Page_Load()` method as `async` I get this compile error:

> The await operator can only be used with an async method.

My code is as such.

```
private DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
private DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
private DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();

protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
    var task1 = GetStoreInfo();
    var task2 = GetSalespersonInfo();
    var task3 = GetManagerInfo();
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
    PopulateAll();
 }
```

}

```
async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> GetStoreInfo()
{
  ds1 = RunStoredProcedureToReturnThisData();
  return ds1;
}

async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> GetSalespersonInfo()
{
  ds2 = RunStoredProcedureToReturnThisData();
  return ds2;
}

async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> GetManagerInfo()
{
  ds3 = RunStoredProcedureToReturnThisData();
  return ds3;
}

protected void PopulateAll()
{
  //Bind the different returned datasets
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has the magic to use async with ASP.NET lifecycle events here

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: This presents me with a debug error of: Error parsing attribute 'async': Type 'AsyncTest.Page1' does not have a public property named 'async'

Comment: So I did this, but the `private async Task PostClaimToService()` function doesn't match the `RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(PostClaimToService()));` call... It expects a function which returns a `BeginHandler` object

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but We keep arriving here.

This is the Microsoft's documentation to handle Async Page_Load(): [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Answer (score -2):

No the ASP.NET design dose not call this method using any form of Task Await, so it cannot be Asnyc