# await Task.Delay(0) Runs OK but await Task.Delay(1000) Does not

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to implement async using Visual Studio 2017. Being new to async, here is my first attempt, which I cannot get to work and also cannot find the answer anywhere on the internet.

`await Task.Delay(any non-zero number)` appears to be in an infinite loop.
`await Task.Delay(0)` executes properly.

What am I missing?

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace TestAsync
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetContentAsync)); //It doesn't seem to matter whether I have this statement or not.
            var contentTask = GetContentAsync();
            Label1.Text = "This is now";
            Label2.Text = contentTask.Result.ToString();
        }

        public async Task<string> GetContentAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(0);  //Any non-zero number appears to cause an infinite loop.
            return "That's all folks";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An async task has to be `await`'ed in order to return anything. Change the signature of your `Page_Load` event handler to be `async void Page_Load` and add the `await GetContentAsync()`

Comment: What do you mean by internal loop?

Comment: By calling `contentTask.Result` you are [blocking on async](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The situation you get is called a deadlock. The zero does not cause a problem because it is [handled as a special case](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,5fb80297e082b8d6) where the function returns immediately.

Comment: `Task.Delay(0)` produces a task that immediately completes synchronously. Any non-zero value gives an asynchronous task and will involve a thread switch. You need to call `ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks` to properly run such tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing a [deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) due to blocking on async code with the call to the Task's `Result` property.

One way implement your page load in this case is as an `async void` method, then using `await` on your method. Using async void does have some unsavory consequences, however.

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "This is now";
    Label2.Text = await GetContentAsync();
}
```

You can now use a non-zero value in your `Task.Delay` without the deadlock occurring.

Using `async void` isn't generally advisable. You should instead register a task in your page load method, then handle the setting of your label within that. Something like this could do the trick:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(SetContentAsync));
    Label1.Text = "This is now";
}

private async Task SetContentAsync() 
{
    Label2.Text = await GetContentAsync();
}
```

Microsoft has an additional article on using async/await within webforms which I would recommend giving a read. You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Comment: `The correct way to implement your page load in this case is as an async void method` - [no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35899982/11683). The linked article explains that `RegisterAsyncTask` has to be used instead, which the OP tries to do (incorrectly). Same is recommended in the documentation you are linking to yourself. In all cases `void Page_Load` remains non-async.

Comment: @GSerg I've updated my answer with a more idiomatic approach based on your comment. Thanks.