# How to Run two methods at each intervals of time in c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

how can I try to run two methods simultaneously at each intervals of time in c#,
I tried with timer and task but the method is firing and it is not displaying.

( there is two data table, it should run simultaneously each other )

method in page load event()

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       object value = null;
       Thread thread = new Thread(() => { value = method(); });
              thread.Start();
              thread.Join();
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = value.ToString() });
       Thread.Sleep(600);

        
       Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => { value = NewMethod(); });
              thread2.Start();
              thread2.Join();
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = value.ToString() });
       Thread.Sleep(600);
  }
```

Comment: For background tasks in web you should use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: There is only one method in your example, where is the second one? Also, there is no way to guarantee concurrency, after all, your program might run on a single core computer.

Comment: You should never try to spin out your own threads from an ASP.NET web app, https://halfblood.pro/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a If you know a little bit more about ASP.NET internals, you will see that results of such background tasks cannot be easily displayed in pages, as the page lifecycle differs a lot.

Comment: this one now am using it is working but two thread running at smae time, but i need second thread run after 1 minute and then after one min again thread 1 and so on, ( menas one after another at each intervals)

Comment: Don't roll your own threads. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899800/can-page-load-be-async) and [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-magic-of-using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45-plus-an-important-gotcha).

Comment: then how can we do two threads run at different time. or nay other methods to run this concept other than thread