ASP.NET and Graph work only in certain condition
Let's start by saying that this problem make me crazy :-)
Backgroung info:
I need to add Graph support to an old project ASP.NET, Framework 4.7.2 and webform.
I know, it's an old and crap technology, but I need it works.
The code (C#) below works fine in a new project ASP.NET core Web App template
    
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;


namespace WebApplication_testGraph.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
   
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var tenantId = "xxx";

            // Values from app registration
            var clientId = "xxx";
            var clientSecret = "xxx";

            // using Azure.Identity;
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var accessToken =  clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes) { });

           // Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
            {
                Message = new Message
                {
                    Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                        Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
                    },
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "xxx@xxx.com",
                },
            },
        },
                },
                SaveToSentItems = false,
            };

             graphClient.Users["xxx@yyy.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
        }

    }
}


But in a project with ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2, C# and Web Form, about the same code do not work.
I have no errors, but nothing really happens
this is the code:

using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Me.SendMail;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public partial class test_email : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected async Task Page_LoadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var tenantId = "xxx";

        // Values from app registration
        var clientId = "xxxx";
        var clientSecret = "xxxx";

        // using Azure.Identity;
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var accessToken = await clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes) { });

        //Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
        {
            Message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "xxxxi@xxx.com",
                },
            },
        },
            },
            SaveToSentItems = false,
        };

        await graphClient.Users["xx@yyy.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

            }
}

Could you help me to understand why the code do not work in this conditions, please?
TNX
I tryed to change
protected async Task Page_LoadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)

in
public async Task Page_LoadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)


I have no errors, but nothing really happens -> I created a new .net framework 4.8 MVC project(I didn't install 4.7 in my machine), then in the HomeController/Index method, I added codes below which worked well.
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "tenantId ";
    var clientId = "clientId ";
    var clientSecret = "clientSecret ";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
    return View();
}

But if the method name is IndexAsync(), I will get 404 error.


Thank you for your reply.
Could you check if it works also with Web Form (not MVC)?

web form have different behavior in async method, make sure method name is protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e), and pls follow this tutorial to write asycn method. Calling MS graph API is async method.

I had a test in my side and I faced the same issue which is "not triggered", then I changed the method name to origin, my codes got triggered but no response, then I noticed it might relate to async mechanism. Then I found this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899800/can-page-load-be-async

I run this test:

New VM from scratch, VS 2022. -New Project ASP.NET, Web Form, C#.
With  "protected async Task Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)"  the page never ends loading (blank page).
I added a peace of simple code to check variables and nothing happens, no values in watch


yes, just like what you post, calling MS graph API requires to async, but the mechanism for async in web form is different. that's the issue.

One step ahead. Finally works as expected
Now the code below works and send email, with attachment, in a ASP.NET 4.8, Web Form, Framework 4.7.2.
The issue was we have to "await" the async task in the Button behavior


public partial class Test_email : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
    }

    protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
          
            await GetGizmosSvcAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }
    public async Task GetGizmosSvcAsync()

           
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var tenantId = "";

        // Values from app registration
        var clientId = "";
        var clientSecret = "";

        // using Azure.Identity;
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var accessToken = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes) { });
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
        {
            Message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "email@email.com",
                },
            },
        },
                Attachments = new List<Attachment>
        {
            new FileAttachment
            {
                OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                Name = "attachment.pdf",
    ContentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/PDF/attach.pdf")), 
            },
        },
            },
        };
             
 

        await graphClient.Users["mailboxeol@somedomain.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

        // fine

    }



